# Setting an initial toolbar item to selected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a toolbar, with two items, both selectable. When I click on an item it shows as selected, as you can see here:

[image]

I'm unable to set an item initially. At first both items are unselected, but I want the first to be selected. This is how things look until I manually click on an item:

[image]

What must I do to set the first item as selected at application startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using `NSToolbar` - use `setSelectedItemIdentifier`.  Each of your items should have a unique Identifier specified in Interface Builder.

For example, I've just created a simple project with an NSToolbar in the main window view, added two items (from the defaults), and hooked up an outlet as below:

AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSToolbar *toolbar;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [self.toolbar setSelectedItemIdentifier:@"NSToolbarShowFontsItem"];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this...the window I'm trying to achieve this with is not my main window. It is in a separate xib file. I don't have a reference to the that window in my app delegate, so I don't know how to use your solution...any tips?

Comment: If you want to make changes to any object you will need to have a reference to it in your code - either by creating it in code or by connecting it in Interface Builder.  I assume you have a UIViewController subclass which loads the xib - that would be where you have the IBOutlet connection.